# Quotation Marks - VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, quotation-marks

I am trying to link a PNG file as image source for a signature  - to send e-mail using vba. I am trying to adjust the size of the signature (PNG Image) as well **trying to understand what a Single Quote and Double quote refers to**. I **need image size to be Height - 1.96 cm and width - 16.37 cm**. Please advise.

```
 "<img src ='" & relativepath1 & "'>" **<--- This one works but signature is too big** 

"<img src='Image1.png'" & "width='500' height='400'>" **<-- Too small. And Image doesn't load**

Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()

relativepath1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Signature99" & ".png"

'Create a new email message
Set OutlookMessage = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutlookMessage
'.Attachments.Add "C:\ Image1.PNG", olByValue, 0
.To = Prime_Email
.cc = cc1
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Donor Volume - " & " " & str2 & "(" & Subject & ")"
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(Range("E2:N16")) & "<img src ='" & relativepath1 & "'>"
.send
'.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutlookMessage = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `"<img src=""Image1.png"" width=""500"" height=""400"">"` or `<img src=""Image1.png"" style=""width:500px;height:400px;"">` You may want to see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Comment: You may also have to use `relativepath1` instead of `Image1.png` if the image still doesn't load. Maybe because it is not able to find the image. For example `"<img src=" & relativepath1 & " width=""500"" height=""400"">"` or `<img src=" & relativepath1 & " style=""width:500px;height:400px;"">`

Comment: @SiddharthRout .. It doesn't work. It still throws me an error "File not found / file moved to a different location".

Comment: Can you share the final code that you are using including the value of `relativepath1` ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout.. Actually resizing the signature worked. But its blurry (When resized). But if the image size can be adjusted it would be helpful. I have added the code to the Question.